# Using legacy projects containing 'System.Web.HttpContext' in ASP.NET Core3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have some legacy projects, written with .Net Framework which should be used by an API project which is written by ASP.NET Core3.1.
The problem is that these legacy projects are using 'System.Web.HttpContext' that you know does not exist in .net core anymore. 
Now we are receiving this error:
'**Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web**, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'
Have you faced this problem before? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are these projects running in .Net Standard? Have you checked compatibility?

Comment: [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: They are still in .Net Framework and we added their dlls as reference to the .net core API Project.
Besides, we have already checked and managed compatibilities via '.NET Portability Analyzer'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET Framework libraries are not technically compatible with .NET Core. .NET *Standard* libraries are, and since both .NET Framework and .NET Core implement .NET Standard, Microsoft made a special exemption in the compiler to allow .NET Framework libraries to be referenced by projects that target .NET Core, *with the caveat that they may not actually work.* You get a warning to this effect when you reference a .NET Framework library from a .NET Core project.

The .NET Framework library will work as long as it *only* uses APIs compatible with .NET Standard 2.0. `System.Web.HttpContext` is *not* one such API, so it will *not* work in a .NET Core project. Period. Nothing you can do about that.

You can attempt to multi-target your libraries and sub-in .NET Core compatible APIs using compiler directives. That'll work, but gets messy quick. Otherwise, you'll just have to write new versions of the libraries for ASP.NET Core, since presumably you're trying to maintain support in the current libraries for ASP.NET.

Comment: multi-target  libraries and sub-in .NET Core compatible APIs using compiler directives ?